# Mongoid: Query for objects where has_many associations have certain field values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I have a `GiftCategory` model:

```
class GiftCategory
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :gifts_count, type: Integer
  has_many :gifts, :inverse_of => :gift_category
end
```

And I have a `Gift` model:

```
class Gift
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :gift_units_count, type: Integer
  has_many :gift_units,      :inverse_of => :gift
  belongs_to :gift_category, :inverse_of => :gifts, :counter_cache => true

  after_save :update_counter

  def update_counter
    self.gift_category_id_change.each do |e|
      GiftCategory.reset_counters(e, :gifts) unless e.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

The `update_counter`method allows me keep count of how many `Gift` objects belongs a `GiftCategory`. This way I can e.g. query only for `GiftCategory` objects that have some `Gift` objects:

```
GiftCategory.where(:gifts_count.gt => 0)
```

**But as you can see**, a `Gift` has a `gift_units_count` field as well. This field keeps count of the number units available of the `Gift`. How can I query for `GiftCategory` objects that has `Gift` objects with `gift_units_count > 0`?

I think that a solution could be something like described [here](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3296), but I can't get closer myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That isn't inherently possible, since the document is referenced.

It's important to remember that `GiftCategory` doesn't actually contain a `Gift`. Instead, the `Gift` records have a field called `gift_category_id`. You essentially would need to find `Gift` records which have a `gifts_unit_count > 0`, then compile a list of their `gift_category_id` fields, unique them, and then retrieve those records.

This would do roughly what I've stated above:

```
gift_category_ids = Gift.where(:gifts_unit_count.gt => 0).map {|g| g.gift_category_id}.uniq
for gift_category_id in gift_category_ids
  gift_category = GiftCategory.find(gift_category_id)
  # do something with this
end
```

As far as I know, Mongoid is not willing to do something like this for you. As someone commented above, you may want to consider embedding, which would allow you to query this way, since the fields will be stored in the same document.

Comment: If you need a criteria: `GiftCategory.where( :id.in => gift_category_ids )`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find a solution for this problem several times already and always gave up. I just got an idea how this can be easily mimicked. It might not be a very scalable way, but it works for limited object counts. The key to this is a sentence from this [documentation](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) where it says:

> Class methods on models that return criteria objects are also treated like scopes, and can be chained as well.

So, instead of writing the update_counter after save hook function and in order to save the GiftCategory.gifts_count field, you can define a class function like so:

```
def self.with_gifts
  ids = GiftCategory.all.select{|gc| gc.gifts.gift_units_count > 0}.pluck(:id)
  GiftCategory.where(:id.in => ids)
end
```

The advantage is, that you can do all kinds of queries on the associated (Gift) model and return those GiftCategory instances, where those queries are satisfied (which was the case for me) and most importantly you can chain further queries like so:

```
GiftCategories.with_gifts.where(:some_field => some_value)
```